# Словарь состоит из списка. Как проверить входит ли данный список в словарь

Tags: python, словари

```
if new_list in dic1:
   ...........
```

Пишет:

> unhashable type: 'list'

Что делать?

Comment: Вот есть вопросы на английском: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257588, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671211 но я не знаю, как указать, что они связанные

Comment: И вот этот тоже https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671376

Comment: не ясно что у вас на входе, что конкретно проверить хотите. Не могли бы вы пример показать: входные словарь, списки и варианты ответов соотвествующие?

Answer (score 1):

Ключами в словаре должны быть хэшируемые объекты, т.е. неизменямые, если говорить о встроенных типах Python (как я понимаю, из того, что объект неизменяемый, следует, что он хэшируемый, обратное же, строго говоря, неверно). Например, можно использовать кортеж как ключ, потому что он неизменяемый, а список - нет. При итерации по словарю проходятся его ключи, а для того, чтоб проверить, есть ли среди его значений что-то (например, список), можно воспользоваться методом словаря `values`:

```
if new_list in dic1.values():
    # сделать что-нибудь
```

https://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь посмотреть есть ли **ВЕСЬ** список в словаре, для того, чтобы обнаружить вхождение, Вам нужно пройти по всем эл-там списка:

```
>>> new_lis = ['a', 's']
>>> new_dict = {'a': 1, 's': 2}
>>> for i in new_list:
...     if i in new_dict: print(True)
... 
True
True
>>>
```

Можно вернуть однозначный ответ с помощью такой функции:

```
>>> def w(new_list, new_dict):
...   for i in new_list:
...     if i not in new_dict:
...       return False
...   return True
... 
>>> w(['a', 's'], {'a': 1, 's': 2})
True
>>> w(['a', 'b'], {'a': 1, 's': 2})
False
```

Comment: Мне кажется, `q = False; break` не очень питонично. `return False` лучше подходит)
А в конце `return True` и не нужны никакие *q*

Comment: @MrMorgan согласен

Comment: вы пытаетесь `set(new_lis).issubset(new_dict)` реализовать? (`all(item in new_dict for item in new_lis)`) Миелофон барахлит сегодня, не понимаю о чём автор спрашивает.

Comment: @jfs да, про `set` совсем забыл, спасибо, отличный пример

Answer (score 0):

Если входной список и словари имеют большой размер, то прямой перебор, достаточно длительный процесс. Можно воспользоваться свойствами множеств:

```
dic1 = {1:"a", 2:"b", 3:"c", 4:"d", 5:"e"}

new_list = [1, 2, 3]
print(set(new_list) <= set(dic1))   # True

new_list = [3, 6]
print(set(new_list) <= set(dic1))   # False
```

Без множеств, можно использовать функции `map` и `all`, чтобы придерживаться python-стиля:

```
print(all(map(lambda x: x in dic1, new_list)))
```